# Why use asyncio Server as context manager *and* call serve_forever()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The Python 3.7 documentation for asyncio streams includes a [TCP echo server example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams):

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

This is the fragment that I'm particularly interested in:

```
async with server:
    await server.serve_forever()
```

So we are doing two things:

- We are using [`asyncio.Server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server) as a context manager, for which (from that page) "it’s guaranteed that the Server object is closed and not accepting new connections when the async with statement is completed".
- We are calling [`Server.serve_forever()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server.serve_forever). This usually starts listening (if not already started) and ensures the server is closed when the coroutine is cancelled. By the time we reach these lines we have already called [`start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) (with the default `start_serving=True`) so the only effect is ensuring the server is closed.

It seems like these are doing essentially the same thing. Why are both lines included in the example? Are most reasonable practical applications likely to include both?

Comment: Your analysis is correct and the example is likely overdoing it. One reason I can think of for `with` is to be explicit about the lexical lifetime of the server, i.e. declare *intent* to have it closed upon exiting the block. That way even if someone modifies `await server.serve_forever()` to, say, `await asyncio.sleep(60)`, the server will still get correctly closed. (But then I'd be still more explicit and write `async with asyncio.start_server(...) as srv: await srv.run_forever()`.)

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring out the answer to this?

Comment: Yes, you only need one or the other. In this case I would go with `await srv.run_forever()` as there would be nothing to wait on otherwise and the function would immediately exit. But anyway I switched from using asuncio to using Trio, which lets you write correct programs much more easily (e.g. in the above I missed `await writer.wait_closed()`, which isn't necessary in Trio).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the unnecessary redundancy can be seen here. The `serve_forever` method can be called if the server is already accepting connections.

In the `Server` object methods description, the `serve_forever` coroutine example is as the follows:

```
async def client_connected(reader, writer):
    # Communicate with the client with
    # reader/writer streams.  For example:
    await reader.readline()

async def main(host, port):
    srv = await asyncio.start_server(
        client_connected, host, port)
    await srv.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main('127.0.0.1', 0))
```

More information can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server.serve_forever).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this, but I don't see how it adds anything. I already referenced the documentation in my question and noted that the calls seemed to do the same thing, and the comment by user4815162342 confirmed it.